# THREE.js. Change mesh position after applying EdgesHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js, mesh

I tried to rotate or change position of a mesh after applying EdgesHelper, but it doesn't work — **mesh stays on the same position**. (Without EdgesHelper it works fine). What am I doing wrong?

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0xcf0000 );

edges.position.z = 100;
edges.position.x = 100;

scene.add( edges );
```

Comment: Can you show a live example by editing this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95t964o0/ ?

Comment: I understood whre is a mistake. I must change position of mesh, but not edges.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the source of THREE.EdgesHelper it seems that the matrixAutoUpdate is set to false. This prevents the computation of the position and rotation on every update.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/EdgesHelper.js

Setting the matrixAutoUpdate of the EdgesHelper to true should do the trick, but calling the .updateMatrix() function after setting the new position or rotation seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, as suggested I added:

```
        egh.matrixAutoUpdate = true;
```

That the edge and the cube followed my coordinates I used:

```
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry(width,height,depth), 
                        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00AA00, side:THREE.DoubleSide, opacity: 0.5, transparent: true } ) );
        scene.add(cube);

        var egh = new THREE.EdgesHelper(cube, 0x777777);
        egh.material.linewidth = 1;
        egh.position.x = cube.position.x;
        egh.position.y = cube.position.y;
        egh.position.z = cube.position.z;
        egh.matrixAutoUpdate = true; // this helped
        scene.add(egh);
```