# Edgeshelper not updating position of mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to draw a coloured box, including the edges (in a different colour)
This is the code I am using to create the box and edges. I have added them both to a object3D since I will have a number of differnt objects in the scene and would like to enforce encapsulation.

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, material );   
var edge = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0xffffff );

var container = new THREE.Object3D();
container.add(mesh);
container.add(edge);

scene.add(container);
```

The above posted code works and produces this:

[image: img]

But when I change the position of the parent object like so:

```
container.position.set(0,30,0);
```

Only the edges are moved. Why?

[image]

Adding .updateMatrix() to the container, mesh, or edges objects doesnt seem to produce different results.

How can the parent object be moved, included all of its children?

Comment: possible duplicate of [THREE.js. Change mesh position after applying EdgesHelper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126938/three-js-change-mesh-position-after-applying-edgeshelper)

Comment: It should be EdgesHelper, not EdgeHelper. But that's not your problem, that's a typo up above.

Comment: @BobWoodley possible duplicate answer says to use .updateMatrix(). But that doesnt seem to work if both the mesh and edge objects are contained within a parent object

Comment: Hey @BuildingJarl, you found a solution to this or used a different approach? I want to add the edges as visual effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the helpers as children of the scene directly.

This is due to the following lines that appear in many of the helpers:

```
this.matrix = object.matrixWorld;
this.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
```

three.js r.70